# Remove duplicate values from an array that's in loop

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have this code that gives back 3 arrays and I want to check for duplicates in all 3 and then keep only 1 value. But because the array is generated in a loop array_unique / array_ diff wont work.

is there any solution for this problem?

```
foreach ($ci AS $i) {
    if($i == 0){
        continue;
    }
    $cfsi = $cate->getCategoriesFeatureID($i);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($cfsi);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

The result I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 19
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 27
)

Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 18
    [5] => 19
    [6] => 20
    [7] => 21
    [8] => 27
    [9] => 28
)

Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 19
    [5] => 27
    [6] => 28
)
```

The result I'm looking for

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 19
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 27
)

Array
(

    [0] => 17
    [1] => 21
    [2] => 28
)

Array
(

    [0] => 11
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is store what was previously displayed and each time only report the differences from the current to this previous value (using [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)).  Then at the end of the loop move the current value to the previous value.

```
$previous = [];
foreach ($ci AS $i) {
    if($i == 0){
        continue;
    }
    $cfsi = $cate->getCategoriesFeatureID($i);
    $difference = array_values(array_diff($cfsi, $previous));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($difference);
    echo "</pre>";
    $previous = $cfsi;
}
```